# PHP Query MySQL with data from CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to compare an email from a CSV file from facebook with the email list in my mysql database.

But when i try to query the sql, nothing happens..

if I echo the email and copy past the email into the query string, then there is not problem.

So what is it I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $array[] = $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$place = explode("  ", $array['94']);

$email = $place['11'];


$x = mysqli_query($mysql_link, "SELECT * FROM `dagenshug_newsletter_subscribe` WHERE mail_address = '" . $email . "'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($x)) {
    $haha[] = $row;
}

print_r($haha);

?>
```

`$place['11']` contains the mail

UPDATE:

I tried to insert it into my database, and here is the result

> j a c o b s e n @ g m a i l . c o m

Comment: First, the var: $email is undefined (you should set instead of echoing it). For print arrays, use var_dump() instead of print_r.

Comment: Somewhere before your SELECT, you need to set ```$email = $place[11]```;

Comment: mistake, because i was testing.. i was trying $email = $place[11].... and even put the $place['11'] into the string.. not working